# Match "which bundle" with echo $PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

Anyone know how I can get these two commands to output the same path?

```
$ which bundle
/Users/mike/.rvm/bin/bundle

$ echo $PATH
/Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@1saleaday1/bin:/Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/bin:/Users/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin:/Users/mike/.rvm/bin:/Users/mike/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

Comment: Unless the answer is `export PATH=$(which bundle)`, I didn't understood your question

Comment: `bundle` is an executable script, `$PATH` is an environment variable. There is no way to make `bundles` location reflect a series of paths as is the value of `$PATH` - they're 2 completely separate things.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same thing.

`echo $PATH` tells you your entire path where you can find executables.  `which bundle` is telling you where in that path the bundle executable is.

Comment: Well, there seems to be an error with my paths, so I thought they should match up.

Answer (score 0):

You can make both commands output the same path using the following line:

```
export PATH=$(which bundle)
```

but since you destroyed your path, you will need to call then with the full path:

```
/bin/which bundle
/bin/echo $PATH
```

This seems to be more a curiosity than a real use case, correct? Even if this is for real use, this is just plain wrong and you should review your constraints.

Comment: Well, I'm having an error with bundler and I figured the paths should be match up. Given you know my paths, any reason why the gem 'bundler' won't install correctly?

Comment: @machito there are a lot of motives for that. Maybe you should open another question and give details, like the output of bundler?

Comment: Since bundler doesn't install, it won't let me run any bundler commands. Any ideas?

Comment: @machito I'm not sure if your problem is that your bundler is not running or you can't install bundler. Anyway, create another question with the command you are running (`bundle install` or `gem install bundler`), and the output, and someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Appreciate your help.